# why is $watch value parameter sometimes a string value and sometimes a function?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-watch

I've seen cases where the first parameter of a $watch is simply a string rather than a function. When do you use a function and when do you use the string?

In this plunker, I did this both ways. The $watch in the controller uses a function, while the $watch in the directive uses a string.  They both work, but I just don't understand the rules as to why it a function in one case and then a string in the other case. Can anyone please explain this to me?

http://plnkr.co/edit/hSdQcRnvYn16ZeeJyPaM?p=preview

```
app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('mainCtrl', MainCtrl);

function MainCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.myColor1 = 'blue';
    $scope.myColor2 = 'blue';

    $scope.$watch(function(scope) {
            return scope.myColor1;
        },
        function(newValue, oldValue) {
            $scope.myStyle = 'color:' + $scope.myColor1
        }
    );
}


app.directive('fontColor', FontColor);
function FontColor() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
            scope.$watch(attrs['fontColor'], function(newVal) {
                console.log(newVal)
                el.css('color', newVal)
            })

        }
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@*" data-semver="3.3.1" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.4" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.5" data-semver="1.4.5" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="mainCtrl" class="container" style="padding-top:30px">

    <div style="{{myStyle}}">color1</div>
    <input type="text" ng-model='myColor1'>
    <br><br>

    <div font-color="myColor2">color2</div>
    <input type="text" ng-model="myColor2">
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

That's just how `$watch` is defined in Angular. You can see the documentation for it here: [`$watch` doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch)

It states that the first argument to `$watch` can be one of either:

- `string`: evaluated as expression, or
- `function(scope)`: called with current scope as parameter